# createdCell not getting created when .draw() is called after data edit

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I'm using the DataTables jQuery plugin.
The table renders as I want it when the DataTable is created on the page load.

The problem is - when i update the data for a row (after editing).  The createdCell I have defined in column 2 is not getting created upon the redrawing the table

```
var SiteTable = $('#dataGrid').DataTable({
...removed settings that do not seem relevant to the problem...
columns: [
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '',
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            orderable: false
        },
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '',
            orderable: false,
            sortable: false,
            createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                $(td).append(
                    $("<button class='btn-edit-row'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></button>")
                );
            }

        },          
        { data: "Site", title: "Site", class: "align-center", sortable: true, orderable: true },
        { data: "OffsetX", title: "Offset-X", class: "align-right", sortable: false, orderable: true }
... removed following columns...
]
}); // END - $('#dataGrid').DataTable
```

Here is my function to collect the edited row data from a form and update the table data.  Neither of the final two lines work as expected.  The table does update with the new data in the expected columns but the createdCell with the button is not populated.

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnSaveData", function (e) {
    // the row currently being edited has this class
    var row = $(".editing");
    var data = SiteTable.row(row).data();

    data.Site = $("#Site").val();
    data.OffsetX = $("#OffsetX").val();
    data.OffsetY = $("#OffsetY").val();
    data.DirectionName = $("#DirectionName").val();
    data.CenteringName = $("#CenteringName").val();
    data.StructureName = $("#StructureName").val();
    data.Source = $("#Source").val();

    $(row).removeClass("editing")

    //SiteTable.row(row).data(data).draw();
    SiteTable.row(row).invalidate().draw();

});
```

Comment: Use a `render()` function instead of `createdCell()`. `createdCell()` is only called once, when the column is created, not when it is updated.

Comment: **Thank you David!!**  This fixed my problem.